# Is it possible to have a static VerticalStackLayout with TextBoxes for input?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have the following `CollectionView` on my app that is bonded to a list.

```
            <CollectionView            
        ItemsSource="{Binding tasks}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center">

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Task">
                    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="15">
                        <Entry Text="{Binding name}" />
                        <Entry Text="{Binding status}"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding deadline}" />
                        <Entry Text="{Binding description}" />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

[image]

I want to have an empty layout similar to this where the user can fill in input always next to the last filled layout.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Are you running into a problem?

Comment: @Jason I don't know where to start even. I know that I have to put a layout plus textboxes but I don't know where. Would you help me, please?

Comment: start with a `VerticalStackLayout` with four `Entry` elements, just like the XAML you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `VerticalStackLayout` with four `Entry` elements like Jason suggested.

Here's the XAML code below for your reference:

```
  <VerticalStackLayout 

            Margin="15"
            WidthRequest="200"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            >

        <Entry Placeholder="Name" Text="{Binding name}" ></Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Status" Text="{Binding status}"></Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Deadline" Text="{Binding deadline}"></Entry>
        <Entry Placeholder="Description" Text="{Binding description}"></Entry>

  </VerticalStackLayout>
```